# What are cURL headers needed for GMail API (message.send)?

Tags: gmail-api, filemaker

I'm trying to get the GMail API working, for sending an Email.  I am building the JSON and cURL requests myself (instead of with a 3rd party library - not able to easily use one of those; and shouldn't need to...)

I got far enough that I have a JSON object that fails when I make the cURL request from my solution (error 400 - Recipient required...), but it WORKS went sent via their 'Try this API' widget on the GMail API docs page.

I'm thinking that I have something wrong in my cURL headers (which would be different between my solution's code and their API widget).  So what cURL headers are required?    I thought I had looked around, but I am not finding the information.  Could be missing something obvious.  :)

URL:  `https://gmail.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send`

cURL headers used (exact syntax is not this, this is just close-representation):

```
 -X POST
 -H Authorization: Bearer <accessToken>
 -H Content-Type: message/rfc822
 -d <JSON>
```

Example JSON object:

````
{"payload":
  {"body":
   {"data":""}
  ,"headers":[
     {"name":"To","value":"email@email.net"}
    ,{"name":"From","value":"email@address.com"}
    ,{"name":"Subject","value":"Test message ---  TESTING"}
  ]
  ,"mimeType":"text/plain"
  ,"partId":"1"
  }
  ,"raw":"TUlNRS1WZX... < rest of encoded RFC2822 content>"
}```
````

Comment: Whhaaaa???  Is their documentation wrong?  I got something to work by changing the URL endpoint:  Worked:     https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?alt=json     This one did NOT Work, but is what docs said:      https://gmail.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send

Comment: You did not change endpoint though - you added parameter

Comment: Ah yes, wrong wording.